# Checking for foreign key in Model clean method - Django 1.7.7 vs 1.8

Tags: django

I have some code in a clean() method that works ok on Django 1.7.7 but stops working in 1.8

The scenario

```
class Span(models.Model):
    happening = models.ForeignKey('Happening', blank = True, null = True)
    soul_class = models.ForeignKey('SoulClass', blank = True, null = True)
```

In the `clean()` method of the `Span` class I have a check as follows

```
if self.happening:
    foo

if self.soul_class:
    bar
```

This was working fine in Django up to 1.7.7 but when I upgrade to Django 1.8 both self.happening *and* self.soul_class are None.

The primary difference appears to be the value of `_soul_class_cache` as follows:

The Span object in **1.7.7** looks like

```
{'end_date': None,
 'id': None, 
 '_state': `<`django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7ff046ac1320`>`, 
 'start_date': datetime.date(2015, 4, 16), 
 'soul_class_id': None, 
 'end_time': datetime.time(14, 12), 
 'happening_id': None, 
 '_happening_cache': None, 
 'start_time': datetime.time(14, 12), 
 '_soul_class_cache': `<`SoulClass: Chi Kung`>` # <-- Here
}
```

In **1.8**

```
{'start_time': datetime.time(14, 0), 
 'end_date': None, 
 'soul_class_id': None, 
 '_state': `<`django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f88d698d2e8`>`, 
 'happening_id': None, 
 '_happening_cache': None, 
 '_soul_class_cache': None, # <-- Here 
 'end_time': datetime.time(15, 0), 
 'id': None,
 'start_date': datetime.date(2015, 4, 16)}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error as such. The functionality has changed.
With 1.7.7 one of these two would be true
`self.happening`  `self.soul_class`
In 1.8 **neither** of them are true so nothing gets done in the `clean()`

Comment: so what is the way to validate something connected with FK in models clean since 1.8?